# Re-usable views or xibs for use with UIStoryboard

Tags: xcode, ios5, uistoryboard

I find it very convenient to use storyboards, especially to have (and show) an overview of the application.

However, I also find it very annoying to replicate the same code and views without the possibility to keep at least a reusable library of the most common xibs.
This is especially true with `UITableView` and its cell.

Did some of you have had any idea or best practice to share for dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking at this yesterday, and it doesn't appear to be possible just yet. I've decided to go for the good old nib in case I want to be able to reuse a view. You can still use them while your main UI is defined in a storyboard using

`UIView *view = [[NSBundle mainbundle] loadNibNamed:@"Nibfile" owner:self options:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this for about two weeks when finally discovery that you have to define if you will work with storyboard or xib files. They aren't going to work together.

I think that is sad too, but until the moment, there's nothing to do about it. The storyboard don't call your xib files and the segues will not work too.

Answer (score 0):

According to several other posts - search storyboard and xib - people are currently using xibs and storyboards together, where xibs can be used to handle re-usable views.  When you create a new file -> iOS -> View or Window, xcode creates a xib for you.